# TreeView with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, treeview, html-lists

How can I connect the list items of a TreeView together? I need something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDxsI.jpg
Currently I get something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P8I8.jpg

I need the connecting lines between the list elements.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Would this work for you http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu  there is a demo page [here]http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/

Comment: Thank you for that. I have already a tree view. I just need something like the connecting lines between the list elements. That's what i need: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gDxsI.jpg not this one: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9P8I8.jpg